# Filtering output lines that are between certain lines

Tags: shell, awk, grep, stdout, output

I've a command that I launch from the bash shell, that outputs a whole bunch of lines.

I want to see all it's output except the lines between lines "Looking for changes" and "Waiting for changes from server"

So let's say the actual output is -

```
Line 1
Line 2
Looking for changes
Line 3
Line 4
Waiting for changes from server
Line 5
Line 6
```

I want to only see -

```
Line 1
Line 2
Looking for changes
Waiting for changes from server
Line 5
Line 6
```

I could write a quick python script that I can pipe this through but was wondering if it could be done with something out of the box, like grep or awk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came out with this solution:

```
$ sed -n -e '1,/Looking/p' -e '/Waiting/,$p' file
Line 1
Line 2
Looking for changes
Waiting for changes from server
Line 5
Line 6
```

- `'1,/Looking/p'` prints from the beginning of the file up to the line containing `Looking`.
- `'/Waiting/,$p'` prints from the line containing `Waiting` up to the end of the file.
- `sed -e` is the way to make sed execute different blocks: `sed -e 'something' -e 'other thing'`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an awk one liner:

```
... | awk '/^Waiting for changes from server$/{p=0}p==0{print}/^Looking for changes$/{p=1}'
```

we use the variable p as a flag. If it is zero, we print the line, otherwise we don't. The flag changes value when we match the lines specified.

Comment: thanks..this works. but I chose the other answer though as this was causing output to buffer and everything would show only at the end when the command finished executing